# Json_tuple says invalid json in hive

Tags: json, parsing, hadoop, hive

I am parsing json stored as rows in a table

It parses the json rows which has simple strings but not the filepaths

for example:

```
{
    "CustomerID": "C101",
    "BillLocation": "C:\Customer\Files\C101\1.txt",
    "CustomerLocation": "NY",
    "Company":"XYZ"
}
```

I tried online json validator it gave error in bill location ,but when appended \ to all where \ was present it validated,
like this `C:\\Customer\\Files\C101\\1.txt`

```
select a.CustomerID,
a.BillLocation,
a.CustomerLocation,
Company from db.jsontable b
LATERAL VIEW json_tuple(b.json,'CustomerId','BillLocation','CustomerLocation','CustomerLocation') a as CustomerId,BillLocation,CustomerLocation,CustomerLocation
```

Comment: 1) Is there a question? 2) Have you checked your code before posting it? (apparently not) 3) If you claim Json_tuple returns an error (and I doubt it) add it to your post

Answer (score 0):

```
select  a.*

from    jsontable b

        lateral view    

        json_tuple
        (
            regexp_replace(b.json,'\\\\','\\\\\\\\')
           ,'CustomerID','BillLocation','CustomerLocation','CustomerLocation','Company'
        ) a as CustomerId,BillLocation,CustomerLocation,CustomerLocation,Company
```

---

```
+------------+------------------------------+------------------+---------+
| customerid |         billlocation         | customerlocation | company |
+------------+------------------------------+------------------+---------+
| C101       | C:\Customer\Files\C101\1.txt | NY               | XYZ     |
+------------+------------------------------+------------------+---------+
```